# PhantomJS - Can't click on any element at a page

Tags: javascript, youtube, phantomjs

**Which version of PhantomJS are you using? Tip: `run phantomjs --version`.**

`2.1.1`

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1.1 Run the first example with: `phantom app.js`

1.2 `open youtube.png`

2.1 Run the second example with: `phantom app.js`

2.2 `open yahoo.png`

**Which operating system are you using?**

`macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195)`

**Did you use binary PhantomJS or did you compile it from source?**

I installed it via `brew install phantomjs`.

**Please provide any additional information below.**

I wrote a script which tries to sign in to YouTube. After when Google updated their styles, I changed it and rewrote it. As far I noticed, phantomJS can't click at any of element on a page. I don't have any idea why... All elements on a page exist, IDs are correct. Here is the source code:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Ffeature%3Dsign_in_button%26next%3D%252F%26hl%3Den%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin';
page.open(url, function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById('identifierId').value = "test@test.com";
    document.getElementBtId('identifierNext').click();
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    page.render("youtube.png");
    phantom.exit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

I rewrote this code to test it on other pages - Yahoo. Everything works as expected. Here is the code:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/';
page.open(url, function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById('uh-search-box').value = "test@test.com";
    document.getElementById('uh-search-button').click();
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    page.render("yahoo.png");
    phantom.exit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

What's wrong? Have you ever had similar situation before?

Comment: `All elements on a page exist, IDs are correct` How can you tell, if you've only made a screenshot `youtube.png`?

Comment: @Vaviloff No, I'm able to make two screenshots. Screen from youtube: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5247571/25772999/19b3fe7a-3276-11e7-9d48-a2460bfee812.png, screen from yahoo: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5247571/25772998/19b3dc24-3276-11e7-9d3b-70b63cbef998.png

Comment: That's not my point. You've made screenshots, ok, but are you sure that selectors you use are actually present on that sign in page? (Most probably they are not). You should check that programmtically. The screen size is 400px wide, I bet Google thinks PhantomJS is a mobile browser and slips it a mobile HTML.

Comment: @Vaviloff Yes, they are present. I tested it also using different screen sizes-
 normal desktop application etc. I won't ask the question if selectors aren't present or screen size is invalid.

Comment: In that case try sending "real" events: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html